# Gatsby / GraphQL App - Rendering and Style Issues When Deployed (Netlify and Surge)

Tags: graphql, gatsby, web-deployment, netlify, surge.sh

Built a portfolio page with `Gatsby` / `GraphQL`, using `styled components`. On my local machine, it looks and functions exactly as I want it to. When deployed, there seem to be button style issues and one of my images isn't rendering at all. I tried deploying on both `Netlify` and `Surge.sh`, but had the same result both times. What am I doing incorrectly? **Edit:** could my button styles be affected by how `Link` is used?

**Here are how my button styles look locally:**
[image]

**Here's how they look deployed** ('View Repo' doesn't even work deployed)**:**
[image]

**My 'About Me' section locally** (2 columns)**:**
[image]

**My 'About Me' section deployed** (only column 1 shows)**:**
[image]

**gatsby-config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `Portfolio`,
    description: `Lorem ipsum.`,
    author: `@jordanwhunter`,
  },
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    `gatsby-plugin-image`,
    `gatsby-plugin-styled-components`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/assets/images`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `videos`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/assets/videos`,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: `gatsby-starter-default`,
        short_name: `starter`,
        start_url: `/`,
        background_color: `#663399`,
        theme_color: `#663399`,
        display: `minimal-ui`,
        icon: `src/assets/images/memoji.jpeg`, // This path is relative to the root of the site.
      },
    },
    `gatsby-plugin-gatsby-cloud`,
    `gatsby-transformer-json`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        path: `./src/data/`,
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "gatsby-starter-default",
  "private": true,
  "description": "A simple starter to get up and developing quickly with Gatsby",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "author": "Kyle Mathews <mathews.kyle@gmail.com>",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.12.0",
    "gatsby": "^3.0.1",
    "gatsby-image": "^3.0.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-gatsby-cloud": "^2.0.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-image": "^1.0.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^3.0.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-offline": "^4.0.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^4.0.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^3.0.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-styled-components": "^4.0.0",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^3.0.0",
    "gatsby-transformer-json": "^3.0.0",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^3.0.0",
    "gh-pages": "^3.1.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.1",
    "surge": "^0.22.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "prettier": "2.2.1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "gatsby"
  ],
  "license": "0BSD",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "develop": "gatsby develop",
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json,md}\"",
    "start": "npm run develop",
    "serve": "gatsby serve",
    "clean": "gatsby clean",
    "test": "echo \"Write tests! -> https://gatsby.dev/unit-testing\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-default"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues"
  }
}
```

**Portfolio.js** (button code starts on line 226)

```
import React from 'react'
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"
import { Button } from "./Button"
import Img from "gatsby-image"
import styled from "styled-components"

const PortfolioContainer = styled.div`
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 5rem calc((100vw - 1300px) / 2);
  background: #fff;
  color: #fff;
`
const PortfolioHeading = styled.div`
  font-size: clamp(1.5rem, 5vw, 2.5rem);
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 5rem;
  color: #000;
`
const PortfolioImg = styled(Img)`
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 10px;
  filter: brightness(100%);
  transition: 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
`
const PortfolioWrapper = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  justify-items: center;
  padding: 0 2rem;

  @media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  }
  
  @media screen and (max-width: 868px) {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }

`
const PortfolioInfo = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  padding: 0 2rem;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .2s, visibility .2s;
  
  @media screen and (max-width: 280px) {
    padding: 0 1rem;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
  }
`
const PortfolioCard = styled.div`
  line-height: 2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: 0.2s ease;

  &:hover ${PortfolioInfo}{
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  &:hover ${PortfolioImg}{
    filter: brightness(50%)
  }
`
const TextWrap = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 375px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  width: 87%;
`
const PortfolioTitle = styled.div`
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin-left: 0.5rem;

  @media screen and (max-width: 280px) {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
`
const PortfolioDescription = styled.div`
  font-size: 1rem;

  @media screen and (max-width: 280px) {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
`
const PortfolioTechnologies = styled.div`
  font-size: 1rem;

  @media screen and (max-width: 280px) {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
`
const ButtonLink = styled.a`
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
`
const ButtonWrap = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: absolute;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: -400px;
  z-index: 1;
  gap: 10px;

  @media screen and (max-width: 280px) {
    padding: 0 1rem;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
  }
`
const CustomButton = styled(Button)`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: -60px;

  @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    padding: 0 !important;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 12px;
    justify-content: center;
  }
`
const CustomP = styled.p`
  font-size: 12px;
`

export default function Portfolio({ heading }) {
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query PortfolioQuery {
      allPortfolioJson {
        edges {
          node {
            alt
            button1
            button2
            description
            name
            technologies
            demo
            repo
            img {
              childImageSharp {
                fluid {
                  ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
                }
              }
            }
          }
        } 
      }
    }
  `)

  function getPortfolio(data) {
    const portfolioArray = []
    data.allPortfolioJson.edges.forEach((item, index) => {
      portfolioArray.push(
        <PortfolioCard key={index}>
          <PortfolioImg 
            src={item.node.img.childImageSharp.fluid.src}
            fluid={item.node.img.childImageSharp.fluid}
            alt={item.node.alt}
          />
          <PortfolioInfo>
            <TextWrap>
              <PortfolioTitle
                css={`
                  margin-top: -500px;
                `}
              >
                <strong><u>Project:</u></strong> <br />
                {item.node.name}
              </PortfolioTitle>

              <PortfolioDescription
                css={`
                  margin-top: -300px;
                  
                `}
              >
                <strong><u>Description:</u></strong> <br />
                {item.node.description}
              </PortfolioDescription>
              <PortfolioTechnologies
                css={`
                  margin-top: -100px;
                 
                `}
              >
                <strong><u>Technologies:</u></strong> <br />
                {item.node.technologies}
              </PortfolioTechnologies>
            </TextWrap>
            <ButtonWrap>
              <ButtonLink
                href={`${item.node.demo}`}
                target="_blank"
              >
                <CustomButton
                  primary="true"
                  round="true"
                >
                  {item.node.button1}
                </CustomButton>
              </ButtonLink>

              <ButtonLink
                href={`${item.node.repo}`}
                target="_blank"
              >
                <CustomButton
                  primary="true"
                  round="true"
                >
                  {item.node.button2}
                </CustomButton>
              </ButtonLink>
            </ButtonWrap>
          </PortfolioInfo>
        </PortfolioCard>
      )
    })

    return portfolioArray;
  }

  return (
    <PortfolioContainer  id="portfolio">
      <PortfolioHeading>
        {heading}
        <CustomP>(Tap on Mobile)</CustomP>
      </PortfolioHeading>
      <PortfolioWrapper>
        {getPortfolio(data)}
      </PortfolioWrapper>
    </PortfolioContainer>
  )
};
```

**About.js** (column 2 code starts on line 137):

```
import React from 'react'
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from 'gatsby';
import { GrCircleInformation, GrCode, GrDocumentImage } from "react-icons/gr";
import styled from "styled-components"
import Img from "gatsby-image"


const AboutContainer = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  background: #fcfcfc;
  color: #000;
  padding: 5rem calc((100vw - 1300px) / 2);
  height: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid gray;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
`
const TopLine = styled.div`
  color: #077bf1;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding-left: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
`
const Description = styled.p`
  text-align: start;
  padding-left: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
  font-size: clamp(1.5rem, 5vw, 2rem);
  font-weight: bold;
`
const ContentWrapper = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  padding: 0 2rem;

  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
`
const ColumnOne = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
`
const Biography = styled.div`
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-right: 2rem;

  h3 {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-style: italic;
  }

  p {
    color: #3b3b3b;
  }
`
const ColumnTwo = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  grid-gap: 10px;

  @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
`
const Image = styled(Img)`
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: -50px;

  @media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
`
export default function About() {
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query MyQuery {
      allFile(filter: {ext: {regex: "/(jpg)|(png)|(jpeg)/"}, name: {in: ["profile-photo"]}}) {
        edges {
          node {
            childImageSharp {
              fluid {
                ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  return (
    <AboutContainer id="about">
      <TopLine>
        About Me
      </TopLine>
      <Description>
        <div css={`display: flex;`}>
          <GrDocumentImage /><h4 css={`font-style: italic;`}>Resumes</h4>
        </div> 
        <div 
          css={`
            display: flex;
            font-size: 14px;
            margin-bottom: -40px;
          `}
        >
          <p>
            <a href="https://docs.google.com/document/d/162ZfqqYxwYgeaY4fk7pf3GdtVn_Kp-ONqWOVCWzIhqo/edit?usp=sharing" target="_blank">Resume 2021 (ATS Version)</a><br />
            <a href="https://docs.google.com/document/d/1u87owpbLG2uoPAqvoVmkuh_LEGSJuRa69OVAYm3hELU/edit?usp=sharing" target="_blank">Resume 2021 (Styled Version)</a>
          </p>
        </div>   
      </Description>
      <ContentWrapper>
        <ColumnOne>
          <Biography>
            <div css={`display: flex;`}>
              <GrCircleInformation /><h3>Brand Statement</h3>
            </div>
            
            <p>
              Full stack web/software developer with an entrepreneurial spirit, and keen sense of efficiency and time management. A passionate, goal-oriented team player that strives to always write clean, precise code focused on mobile responsive themes. Maintains a problem solving, can-do attitude and exhibits consistent eagerness to learn new technologies/techniques.
            </p>
          </Biography>
          <Biography>
            <div css={`display: flex;`}>
              <GrCode />
              <h3>Technologies</h3>
            </div>
            
            <p>
              JavaScript, React, Preact, Next, Gatsby, Svelte, Node, Express, Firebase, Vercel, MongoDB, MySQL, Handlebars, jQuery, D3, GraphQL, Material-UI, CSS3, Bootstrap, Materialize, Bulma, HTML5 
            </p>
          </Biography>
        </ColumnOne>
        <ColumnTwo>
          {data.allFile.edges.map((image, key) => (
            <Image 
              key={key}
              src={image.node.childImageSharp.src}
              fluid={image.node.childImageSharp.fluid}
            />
          ))}
        </ColumnTwo>
      </ContentWrapper>
    </AboutContainer>
  )
};
```

Comment: thanks for the response. could you elaborate?

Comment: just show it live, what is deployment url

Comment: jordanwhunter.netlify.app

Comment: Is the locally screenshot made under `gatsby build && gatsby serve`?

Comment: Try ending the styled-components with a semicolon (it seems to be the solution in some cases: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/16039#issuecomment-564284114=

Comment: Thanks so much for the response. I added semicolons to all of my styled components but there was no change when I re-deployed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspect generated html:

```
<div class="Portfolio__ButtonWrap-zwd7jb-14 boxtca">
  <a href="https://filmapi.vercel.app/" target="_blank" class="Portfolio__ButtonLink-zwd7jb-13 dHdqal">
    <a primary="true" round="true" class="Button-sc-1t76fnu-0 Portfolio__CustomButton-zwd7jb-15 iA-DhcJ cycuPQ">View App</a>
  </a>
  <a primary="true" round="true" class="Button-sc-1t76fnu-0 Portfolio__CustomButton-zwd7jb-15 iA-DhcJ cycuPQ">
    <a primary="true" round="true" class="Button-sc-1t76fnu-0 Portfolio__CustomButton-zwd7jb-15 iA-DhcJ cycuPQ">View Repo</a>
  </a>
</div>
```

### Observation #1:

- bad structure for a second button (not a `ButtonLink`);

### Why:

- messed virtual DOM [and as a result real DOM];

### Possible reason:

- multiple, the same kind children rendered without `key` prop (the most frequent bad React rendering reason?);

### Solution #1: always use a `key` prop for [elements of] lists/arrays/groups!

---

### 'About me' missing column problem:

### Observation #2:

- before (at first render) and during [image] loading html/DOM structure is OK;

React update (rerendering) breaks child divs [of `AboutContainer`] - no `key`s used (then no unique identifiers for multiple divs in VDOM), result - the update breaks the content structure.

But this is not the only reason - the real one was using `<Img/>`-based component - outdated for new gatsby image plugins [versions].

### Solution #2:

### You should use `<GatsbyImage/>` components.

Comment: My <PortfolioCard> component is the parent for everything else rendered in the card, and it uses key={index}. The image missing on my 'About Me' page also has a key={key} when mapped. Do i need to add more?

Also I added semicolons to all styled components, and re-deployed. No change in issue, however.

Comment: `key` prop is required for ALL multiple children/entries [the same type - divs, in this case] at ANY depth level !! required at least for `<ButtonLink/>`s (2 childs), `<ColumnOne/>`, `<ColumnTwo/>` (2 childs), both **de facto the same div type, not different component/react types**

Comment: thanks so much for this info!! would it be best to set all keys within Portfolio children to key={index} then? or should i create random keys using Math.random() or something?

Comment: don't forget to accept the answer (if works) ;) ... `<TextWrap/>` children: info/description/technologies ... **any multiple styled divs at the same level** ... `<PortfolioCard key={index}>` already has a children with `key`s - index is good enough for non-dynamic contents (not rerendered, not long lists to be optimized)

Comment: definitely will once i get it working :) i added key={index} to each `<TextWrap>` child. Didn't seem to change. Would it help/make any difference to use key={Math.random()} ?

Comment: what about keys for earlier mentioned ButtonLink, columns ??

Comment: set both `ButtonLink` components to key={index}. also set `ColumnOne` component to have a key={1} and `ColumnTwo` component to have a key={2}. nothing is fixed when it redeploys on Netlify.

Comment: most recent repo: https://github.com/jordanwhunter/portfolio

Comment: different key for differnt child at the level !! Both ButtonLink has the same - sharing index is not enough

Comment: `TopLine` and `ContentWrapper` are both divs at the same level, both needs a `key`

Comment: Added random keys to literally every component and still those components aren't rendering when deployed. Repo is updated for reference.

Comment: keys for top level containers? strange that ... after clicks on menu everything is ok

Comment: yeah i went back and added to top level containers. if you have a moment to take a look over the repo again, i'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Now, I think it can be image-plugins related - should be updated ... https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/release-notes/image-migration-guide/#component-changes

Comment: i managed to get the about me section to finally render out the second column. i changed it to `StaticImage` and it displayed. however, it cannot be placed into a `styled-component` so i'm limited as far as media queries go. still have to figure out why the second link isn't working on portfolio. that shouldn't have anything to do with image-plugins or graphql

Comment: figured out the mobile resizing for `StaticImage` in the about me. now just have to fix links/buttons on `portfolio.js`

Comment: adapt portfolio images to GatsbyImage, too ... for some reasons loading [bigger] images breaks other VDOM nodes, not only images

Answer (score 0):

**Always make sure the documentation you're referencing is current!**

There are significant syntax changes with `graphql` and using the `GatsbyImage` / `StaticImage` components from `gatsby-plugin-image` instead of the `Img` component from `gatsby-image`.

To fix `Portfolio.js` - the image rendering was affecting the button links - code had to be refactored for the current syntax referencing the `GatsbyImage` component from `gatsby-plugin-image`. `graphql` and `useStaticQuery` syntax also had to be refactored. For more information, visit [Gatsby's documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/release-notes/image-migration-guide/#component-changes) (thanks to [@xadm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6124657/xadm) for pointing me in the right direction).

`About.js` was also fixed by updating syntax...except this `Img` tag was changed to `StaticImage` and `graphql` and `useStaticQuery` were removed entirely.